# What tools in QGIS can be used for calculating habitat structural diversity?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, dem, lidar, habitat-modeling

I have a canopy height model derived from a LiDAR DTM and DSM and I would like to calculate or illustrate habitat structural diversity from the canopy height model file. I have tried using roughness but would like to explore other tools. Are there other tools available in QGIS/GRASS etc to do this?

Comment: If you are doing predictive modeling using machine learning, one common approach is to calculate a variety of grid metrics from your raw point cloud data. These grid metrics essentially describe the structure of the forest. The lidR package in R and the FUSION command line tools allow you to generate grid metrics. Also look into the Rumple Index using lidR.

Comment: @Aaron thank you for the suggestions, I do not have the raw point cloud data unfortunately, only raster grids of the DSM and DTM. Can these same metrics be applied to the grids? I would ideally prefer to use QGIS as I have limited experience with R

Comment: Grid metrics require point cloud data. Rumple Index can be generated using a canopy height model (DSM) in lidR. You would have to do a bit of research on a QGIS implementation.

Comment: Here are a couple of papers that may provide some context to your question: https://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/1/4/776 and https://www.fs.fed.us/rm/pubs_other/rmrs_2009_hudak_a002.pdf